# Cannot find official Oracle doc for cursor+ select for update skip locked

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle19c, database-cursor, select-for-update

I'm using Oracle 19c.

In a concurrent environment, when I want to lock a single row I do the following

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur IS
  SELECT id, name
    FROM sample
    ORDER BY id ASC
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
cur_record cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur;
  FETCH cur INTO cur_record;
  CLOSE cur;
  -- do some work with cur_record
END;
```

Please note that it does not limit rows (e.g. rownum) when declaring `CURSOR`. The row is locked on demand when the `FETCH` is executed.

I tested and it works as expected.

What I would like to know is if there is any official Oracle documentation, article or specification that indicates/back the following statement:

*When I have a `cursor` with `select for update skip locked` then the records are locked on demand every time I do `fetch`.*

Answer (score 0):

The FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

Comment: It is unclear whether this answers the question "is if there is any official Oracle documentation, article or specification that indicates/back the following statement: When I have a cursor with select for update skip locked then only the fetched records are locked."? If it does answer the question then you should quote the relevant part of documentation that contains the answer. If there is no relevant quote then this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found detailed documentation about SKIP locked.

We have had some difficulties with SKIP locked as sometimes too many rows got skipped/locked. One of explanations is here, that there could be block level locks in place:
https://markjbobak.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/unintended-consequences/